# geometry nodes proximity issue when target object moved

Tags: geometry-nodes

1st image = correct
instance endpoints on object

[image]

2nd image = incorrect
instance endpoints not on object at new location
seems they still target the original location

[image]

watdo
[image]

Comment: seems i need to include the object info's location data but idk what to plug it into. 
also just realized i didn't even include the proximity nodes in the first image lol. 
i'll share the node setup to whoever is willing to help.

Comment: Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ? And to be sure I get what is the difference between "correct" and "incorrect", you try to draw some electrical arcs between some rotating (?) blade (?) tips and the surrounding wire frame ?

Comment: @StefLAncien i attached the file above. you'll see what i mean by correct/incorrect when you open the file, just press play and watch the arcs. correct = arc endpoints extending from blade, targeting wireframe. incorrect = arc endpoints targeting original wireframe location when moved. select all "main" collection objects and rotate on z axis about 100 degrees to create the error shown above in image 2. thanks for the help.

Comment: Using Blender 3.6.5, I failed to reproduce the "incorrect" solution. I selected the "main" collection (in Outliner: RMB/Select Objects), then I rotated it (in 3DViewport: R/Z/100). It looks very much the same as original view, before rotation. However, I noticed () without and with rotation) that some arcs are extending outside of the wireframe, as if the proximity node is failing. But I have to dig more in your GN graph to understand if this is an error, or because of some other "randomizers"...

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're pointing here to an object that acts as a ghost and partially exists:

[image]

Use "Torus.001" instead and that should solve the issue.